# Warning on updating Mongoid Gem to Version 5 Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid4, mongoid5

I have updated the mongoid gem to 5  from mongoid-4 on rails 4 application. I am facing the following warning on app restart

```
W, [2017-02-15T13:59:49.356541 #14483]  WARN -- : MONGODB Unsupported client option 'max_retries'. It will be ignored.

W, [2017-02-15T13:59:49.356739 #14483]  WARN -- : MONGODB 
Unsupported client option 'retry_interval'. It will be ignored.

W, [2017-02-15T13:59:49.356877 #14483]  WARN -- : MONGODB Unsupported client option 'username'. It will be ignored.
```

How to update Mongoid Yml to remove the warning?

Also This is current YML file

```
staging:
    clients:
      default:
         database: chillr_api
         hosts:
            - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :nearest
    # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
    # low amounts for fast failures.
          max_retries: 1
          retry_interval: 0
          username: 'username'
          password: 'username'
```

Comment: Just remove the option?

Comment: No I was wondering How to enable this in Mongoid 5

Comment: Yea.I think.      max_retries: 1 and retry_interval are Moped configurations which is removed in mongoid 5

Answer (score 0):

Okey.Seems that  max_retries and retry_interval are Moped configuration . Since Moped is taken away in Mogoid 5 This could be removed from configuration .Yml example